# How to add a picture to an excel document into a specific cell using Oleobjects?

Tags: python, excel, image

```
import win32com.client as win32

xl=win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible=0
workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'D:\TestSummary_L.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
obj=sheet.OLEObjects()
dest_cell=sheet.Cells(12, 4)
obj.Add(ClassType=None, Filename="profile_photo.png", DisplayAsIcon=True, Left=dest_cell, Top=dest_cell, Width=50, Height=50)

workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
xl.Quit()
```

This code works on other PCs so I don't know if there is a problem with some settings for my Excel application or I need to do some changes on my code. I get this error.

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

> File
> "C:/Users/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/work_with_excel.py",
> line 10, in 
> obj.Add(ClassType=None, Filename="profile_photo.png", DisplayAsIcon=True, Left=dest_cell, Top=dest_cell, Width=50,
> Height=50)   File
> "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\OLEObjects.py",
> line 38, in Add
> , IconLabel, Left, Top, Width, Height pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Cannot
> insert object.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1